# How to show multiple info window on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I tried to create multiple info windows on google map android. It does not provide any features like that. How can I show multiple info windows at a time on google map?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0LDx.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't show multiple info window on map at a time. But You can create custom marker with info window when you need to show info window then you show that view of marker, else hide view from marker.

In both case you need to recreate marker.